# Python: "is not None" not working as expected

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

In a multi-page survey application I am creating I have a jQuery UI slider bar which is used to provide a rating for an image. This returns a numerical value to my Python/Django view which is stored in a list `slider_DV_values`

On a later Data Verification survey page the participant is given the opportunity via another jQuery slider bar to update the rating they assigned the image.

My issue is that the jQuery UI slider bar only returnes a numerical value if the participant changes it. Therefore the original rating is getting overwritten, with nothing, if the participant does not update it.

However if they do update their rating the new value is getting stored.

If I try

```
    elif step == 13:
        slider_value1 = self.request.POST.get('slider_value1')

        print "This is slider_value1", slider_value1

        if slider_value1 is not None:
            slider_DV_values.pop(0)                
            slider_DV_values.insert(0, slider_value1)
```

The original values stored in `slider_DV_values` are still getting overwritten, with nothing.

I thought the `is not None` would have prevented an empty value from being used to overwrite the original value? IS this not correct?

**Can anyone tell me how to prevent the original values from getting overwritten unless the new value is an updated numerical value?**

Thanks, Deepend

**EDIT**

To see how I am getting my values this is the jQuery slider bar in a page of my `SurveyWizardView` the value of which is returned via the hidden form element

```
<div class="DV_image_row">          
        <div class="DV_image_left">             
            <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{first_image}}{{fourth_image}}{{seventh_image}}" height="300" width="250" style="border:1px solid black;" align="middle"/>                          
                      <div class="DV_slider_one" id="one"></div>                        

                        <script >                                                                               
                            $('#submit').click(function() {
                                var username = $('#hidden').val();
                                if (username == "") username = 0;  
                                $.post('comment.php', {
                                    hidden: username
                                }, function(return_data) {
                                    alert(return_data);
                                });
                            });

                            $(".DV_slider_one").slider({            
                                animate: true,
                                range: "min",
                                value: {{first_slider}}{{forth_slider}}{{seventh_slider}},
                                min: -100,
                                max: +100,
                                step: 1,

                                slide: function(event, ui) { 
                                  $("#slider-result_left").html((ui.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + ui.value);

                                  if($(this).attr("id") ==  "one")
                                      $("#hidden2").val((ui.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + ui.value);
                                }
                            });

                        </script>   


                    <div id="slider-result_left">{{first_slider}}{{forth_slider}}{{seventh_slider}}</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="slider_value1" id="hidden2"/>        


      </div>
```

Comment: is not None chceck for type of the variable, and unless the variable comes directly from python then it's very unlikely to be none. More likely an empty string.

Comment: By nothing do you mean it's being overwritten as an empty string? If yes, then you should try `if slider_value1 != ''`

Comment: @akshay Worked perfectly, If you write up your solution as an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the simple `if slider_value1 != ''` . This is a better option than `if not slider_value1` because the latter will block out `0` also which you might not want to do.

Answer (score 7):

`"" is None` is `False`

**ONLY** `None is None` is `True`

perhaps you just want `if not slider_value1 :` which is true for ANY falsey value (empty string,empty list, empty tuple, false, 0 , None , etc)

Comment: `Only None is None is True` sounds funny

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, as @akshay pointed out I am getting an empty string returned which is not "None" so therefore my if statement does not work. I tried your suggested `if not slider_value1 :` but this still allowed my original value to be overwritten.